# Function is not being called from the componentDidMount method

Tags: javascript, react-native

The problem is that the _requestPermission function is not being called from the componentDidMount method.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    _requestPermission = () => {
      Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
        // Returns once the user has chosen to 'allow' or to 'not allow' access
        // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
        console.log(response)
      })
    }  
  }
```

I already tried to remove it out of the componentDidMount and trigger it with a button. After this the function was started as expected and the Storage permission was requested. How do I make this function to be invoked as this component is rendered? I am open to any solutions, not just triggering it from the componentDidMount.

This is the code of my whole component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native'
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    height: 200,

    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: 'white',
  },

});


export default class Cam extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.takePicture = this.takePicture.bind(this)

  }

  takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true }
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    _requestPermission = () => {
      Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
        // Returns once the user has chosen to 'allow' or to 'not allow' access
        // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
        console.log(response)
      })
    }  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {this.camera = ref}}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            position: 'relative'
          }}
        >
        </RNCamera>

        <ActionButton size={80} useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="Settings" onPress={this.props.switchScreen}>
            <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="Permission" onPress={this._requestPermission}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="Start" onPress={this.takePicture}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>

        </ActionButton>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a function to `_requestPermission`, but actually never call it. Instead just call `Permissions.request` directly e.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
      Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
        // Returns once the user has chosen to 'allow' or to 'not allow' access
        // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
        console.log(response)
      })
    } 
  }
```